# Create a Clojure lazy seq from another lazy seq, combining some elements, removing others

Tags: clojure

Suppose I have a lazy sequence of single character strings, containing only 'A' 'B' and 'C'.

I'd like to create from it a second sequence that contains every 'A' concatenated with as many 'B's as directly follow the 'A'.

For example, input sequence 'C' 'B' 'A' 'B' 'B' 'A' 'A' 'B' 'C' would produce the sequence
'ABB' 'A' 'AB'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
(defn austin [coll]
  (lazy-seq
   (when-let [[x & xs] (seq coll)]
     (if (= x "A")
       (let [[bs other] (split-with #(= % "B") xs)]
         (cons (apply str x bs) (austin other)))
       (austin xs)))))

(austin '("C" "B" "A" "B" "B" "A" "A" "B" "C")) ;=> ("ABB" "A" "AB")
```

First, we use `when-let` to either destructure the input collection to its first and rest (`x` and `xs`), or return `nil` - terminating the recursion - if `coll` is empty.

Next, we check if `x` is `"A"`. If it is, we use [`split-with`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/split-with) to split the remaining items into two seqs, one of any `"B"`s that follow immediately and the other of everything else. We then use `str` to combine the `"A"` with whatever `"B"`s we found and `cons` that onto a recursive continuation of the process.

Answer (score -1):

This is probably not the best solution, but here is working code using `clojure.core/for`.

```
(def abc '("C" "B" "A" "B" "B" "A" "A" "B" "C"))
=> #'user/abc
(for [i (range (count abc))
      :let [a (nth abc i)]
      :when (= a "A")]
  (apply str a (for [j (range (inc i) (count abc))
                     :let [b (nth abc j)]
                     :while (= b "B")]
                 b)))
=> ("ABB" "A" "AB")
```